# Unpack a war file to a destination folder without verbose output

Tags: command-line, unzip

i need to extract a war file with `unzip` without verbose output

i am doing it like this -

`unzip myFile.war -d /home/app/`

but this creates verbose output. How can i prevent that ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can unzip quietly, just use the -qq option (see `man unzip`)

```
   -q     perform  operations  quietly  (-qq  = even quieter).  Ordinarily
          unzip prints the names of the files it's extracting or  testing,
          the extraction methods, any file or zipfile comments that may be
          stored in the archive, and possibly a summary when finished with
          each  archive.   The -q[q] options suppress the printing of some
          or all of these messages.
```

Your command becomes:

```
unzip -qq myFile.war -d /home/app/
```